# Parsing JSON into a correct struct format

Tags: json, swift, decoding

Being pretty new to swiftUI development and don't understanding much at the moment I am sorry if this question have already been answered but I couldn't find (or at least understand) anything to solve my problem. To practice, I am trying to create a first app, a flag quizz. While probably being very easy to do, I am having a hard time trying to answer these two questions :

1. What would be the best solution to store the flag images ? Would in it be in the asset folder, trying to retrieve them from an API or storing them in a free backend service as Firebase if I need to create more functionalities to the app ?
2. I went for the API solution on my side but I am struggling to get it properly done. I'd like to have an array of "Flag" structs allowing me to randomly pick a "Flag" to be displayed in the view with its associated "shortName" (to retrieve the correct flag from the URL) and "Name". Here is what I have so far :

```
import Foundation

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

struct Flag: Codable, Identifiable {
    var flagLink: String
    var flagDetails: FlagDetails
    var id = UUID()
    
    init(flagLink: String, flagDetails: FlagDetails) {
        self.flagDetails = flagDetails
        self.flagLink = "https://flagcdn.com/w320/\(flagDetails.shortName).png"
    }
}

struct FlagDetails: Codable {
    var shortName: String
    var name: String
}


func getJSON(){
    
    guard let urlJSON = URL(string: "https://flagcdn.com/fr/codes.json") else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlJSON) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && data != nil {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]
                print()
    
            } catch {
                print("Invalid data: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

The JSON file provided by the website is following this format :

```
{
    "ad": "Andorra",
    "af": "Afghanistan",
    "ag": "Antigua-et-Barbuda",
    "ai": "Anguilla"
}
```

With the dictionary created, I'd like to assign the CodingKey to "shortName" and the value of the CodingKey to "name" in order for the link to be correctly initialized once I request a random question from the view.
I'm pretty sure this is definitely not the best way to do it but as a true beginner, working a little bit with JSON file can help me a lot.

Many thanks for any help you can provide !

Comment: For first question: It depends what you want: 
* if those are static images that never change, and you want them immediately, store them in assets folder.
* if you want to allow "dynamic" images, and may change them from invocation to invocation, get them from the network location. 
* in the case of network retrieval, if you don't want to wait until they load every time (e.g. on app start), you can also cache them locally on device at runtime, but not as assets).

Comment: In case of network retrieval you need to remember that images from network are not always available (could be anything from networking issue to some temp unavailability of where you host your API), so even with caching you have to provide a "fallback" for cases when images could not be obtained.

Comment: You can probably get the same country name info from `Foundation.Locale`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers @klangfarb and Sulthan ! I think the cache might indeed be the best solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. I would use a framework to download the images, like Kingfisher or ImageLoaderSwift.
2. As for answering your second question:

You can loop through the dictionary, using `for KEY in DICTIONARY`, and then add values to an array (`countryFlags`).

You only need Codable if you can directly convert a json string to a struct, which you can't in this case, because you need an array and not a dictionary.

Mind you, I'm not on a Mac, so I can't test the code.

```
struct Flag {
  /.../

  // Simplified constructor for you
  init(shortName: String, name: String) {
      self.flagDetails = FlagDetail(shortName: shortName, name: name)
      self.flagLink = "https://flagcdn.com/w320/\(shortName).png"
  }
}

struct FlagDetails {
    /.../
}

var countryFlags = [Flag]()

func getJSON(){
    
    guard let urlJSON = URL(string: "https://flagcdn.com/fr/codes.json") else {
        print("Invalid URL")
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlJSON) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil && data != nil {
            do {
                // Changed [String: Any] to [String: String]
                let countryDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: String]

                // NEW CODE
                for (shortName, name) in countryDictionary {
                  countryFlags.append( Flag(shortName: shortName, name: name) )
                }

                print(countryFlags)

            } catch {
                print("Invalid data: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete answer and your time! I just tried and it worked ! I'd just have a small complementary theoritical question. It provides me with something like this : [GuessTheFlag.Flag(flagLink: "https://flagcdn.com/w320/lu.png", flagDetails: GuessTheFlag.FlagDetails(shortName: "lu", name: "Luxembourg"), id: 55EEF2B5-90AF-4BBA-88EC-6403EA67D5E4)]. Do you know why the name of the app "GuessTheFlag" has to appear to refer to the structs when building the array ?

Comment: You mean when printing it? It's just a way of referencing a variable. Nothing to think about, really.

Comment: `options: .mutableContainers` `mutableContainer` isn't useful here.